# Docker compose multi-container with zookeeper, kafka and python script on Azure container instances not able to connect to kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, docker-compose, apache-zookeeper, azure-container-instances

I am trying to get a zookeeper/kafka non-clustered setup to be able to talk to containers with python scripts. I want to be able to run a zookeeper/kafka container and 2 or more containers with python scripts communicating to the zookeeper/kafka, all running in containers or container groups on Azure.

To test this, I have created the below docker container group, with zookeeper and kafka as 2 services and a 3rd service that starts a simple python script to produce a steady pace of messages to a kafka topic. The docker-compose.yml that I am using is as follows:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    container_name: zookeeper
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 2181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000
    ports:
      - 22181:2181
    networks:
      - my-network

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    container_name: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
    ports:
      - 29092:29092
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:9092,PLAINTEXT_HOST://localhost:29092
      KAFKA_LISTENER_SECURITY_PROTOCOL_MAP: PLAINTEXT:PLAINTEXT,PLAINTEXT_HOST:PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_INTER_BROKER_LISTENER_NAME: PLAINTEXT
      KAFKA_OFFSETS_TOPIC_REPLICATION_FACTOR: 1
  kafka_producer:
    build: ../kafka_producer
    image: annabotkafka.azurecr.io/kafka_producer:v1
    container_name: kafka_producer
    depends_on:
      - kafka
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/kafka_producer
    networks:
      - my-network
    environment:
      KAFKA_SERVERS: kafka:9092
networks:
  my-network:
    driver: bridge
```

The kafka_producer.py script is as follows:

```
import os
from time import sleep
import json
from confluent_kafka import Producer

def acked(err, msg):
    if err is not None:
        print("Failed to deliver message: {0}: {1}"
              .format(msg.value(), err.str()))
    else:
        print("Message produced: {0}".format(msg.value()))

# Function to send a status message out on the status topic
def send_status(producer,counter):
    msg = {'counter':counter}
    json_dump = json.dumps(msg)
    producer.produce("counter", json_dump.encode('utf-8'), callback=acked)
    producer.poll()

# Define kafkaProducer to push messages to the status topic
producer = Producer({'bootstrap.servers': 'kafka:9092'})

for j in range(9999):
    print("Iteration", j)
    send_status(producer, j)
    sleep(2)
```

When I 'docker-compose up' this on my Ubuntu 20.04 dev machine, I get the expected behaviour: a stead stream of messages sent to the kafka producer.

After I 'docker-compuse push' this to Azure Container instances and create a container in Azure with the image, the kafka_producer script appears to no longer be able to connect to the kafka broker at kafka:9092.

These are the logs from the container group after startup:

```
Iteration 0
%3|1629363616.468|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka:9092/bootstrap]: kafka:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': Name or service not known (after 25ms in state CONNECT)
%3|1629363618.465|FAIL|rdkafka#producer-1| [thrd:kafka:9092/bootstrap]: kafka:9092/bootstrap: Failed to resolve 'kafka:9092': Name or service not known (after 22ms in state CONNECT, 1 identical error(s) suppressed)
Iteration 1
Iteration 2
```

I had understood that the container group is on the same network subnet and on a single host so I would expect this to operate the same as on my dev machine locally.

My next step will be the have separate containers with different python scripts that I will want to communicate with kafka in this container group. Having the producer script within the same container group is not my longterm expectation, but I believed this simpler setup should work.

Any suggestions for where I am going wrong?

Comment: Where are you actually running Kafka in Azure? I highly doubt you're running it in a containe (or at least, you definitely shouldn't as its data isn't persistent). You should read this post anyway https://www.confluent.io/blog/kafka-listeners-explained/

Comment: @OneCricketeer I am indeed running it in a container instance. In my use-case, kafka is providing asynchronous messaging between multiple scripts. The lack of persistence is not an issue in this case. I’ll check the link you shared shortly.

Comment: Sure, but my point is that you could/should run Kafka either in an actual, persistent VM instance / AKS, or use Event Hubs in Kafka mode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From Azure documentation

> Within a container group, container instances can **reach each other via localhost** on any port, even if those ports aren't exposed externally on the group's IP address or from the container.

This makes it sound like the containers are using a host network, not a Docker bridge like you've setup in Compose (where your code works fine)

Therefore, you ought to connect with `localhost:29092`

If you don't actually need message persistence, then I'd suggest using sockets via HTTP, gRPC or Zeromq between your scripts rather than a Kafka container

Comment: Thanks for the good feedback. Have been exploring Event Hubs and that looks to be a far better solution than creating a container with zookeeper and kafka.